# Is there a way to update and send the name to the response after calling the save method in spring?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, annotations, one-to-one

There are employees and department class as below.

**Employee**

```
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    private Department department;
}
```

**Department**

```
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

I want to save the employee and return the name of the department together.

**Service**

```
public ResponseEntity<Employee> create(Employee employee) throws URISyntaxException {
    Employee savedEmployee = repository.save(employee);
    URI location = new URI(String.format("/employee/%s", savedEmployee.getId()));
    return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(savedEmployee);
}
```

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Employee> postEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) throws URISyntaxException {
    return service.create(employee);
}
```

I want to receive the response as below.

Request Body :

```
{
    "name":"David",
    "department":{
        "id":1
    }
}
```

Actual Response Body:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "David",
    "department": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": null
    }
}
```

Wanted Response Body :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "David",
    "department": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "HR"
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way?

Comment: If department name is not passed in the request while saving in db. Then it will be saved as null in the db.
Or if it is a one to one mapping with department is already saved in db, then u can fetch department details with a select query and update the response object before returning the response.

Comment: Is there any other way but to select and update it?

Comment: If you are saving Department and Employee in different calls and you expect the department details in save-employee-details call, then you have to explicitly fetch it and add in the response.